# How to select single quote mark exist records using oracle regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

```
Table Name : Student

----------------
ID | NAME | ADDRESS
----------------
1 | Mark | Queen's Road
2 | Ann  | Church Road
3 | Sam  | Temple Road
```

I need to get single quote exist records.
ex : -

Select * from student where REGEXP_LIKE(Address,'I NEED SingleQuote Exist Records')

Then my expect result :

```
1 | Mark | Queen's Road
```

Comment: There is no need to use a regular expression function in this situation, unless you have to. Simple `instr(address, q'[']') > 0` predicate is enough.

Comment: thanks dear  Nicholas.i sorted it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape a quote in Oracle by doubling it.

So, using the regular `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE address LIKE '%''%'
```

With `REGEXP_LIKE` you'd have to perform a similar escaping:

```
SELECT * 
FROM student 
WHERE  regexp_like (address, '''+')
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about oracle but in Mysql following query will work for your purpose

```
select * from student where address like "%'%"
```

Comment: Dear Fathah Rehman, Its gives this error.
ORA-00904: "%'%": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: In Oracle it would be: like '%''%'

That is: Single ' to start the string, a %, a single ' to escape the ', the ' itself, a % and a ' to end the string.